# Как подтвердить лот выставленный на продажу steampy python

Tags: python, steam

Всем привет, мне нужно подтвердить лот выставленный на продажу с помощью steampy
Я нашел нужные мне функции в документации, а именно _get_confirmations и confirm_sell_listing
https://github.com/bukson/steampy/blob/master/steampy/confirmation.py
Но не знаю как их можно использовать

Comment: Либа автоматически подтверждает в новых версиях